# how to sync localhost and VPS

Tags: networking, vpn, sync, git

I'm a web geek and totally new to server side Fields.Our University have over 40 branches within the country and we now going to have a web based system to dealing with student registration,payments,marks etc.but if we have any Internet problem (net down stage) we are planning to have a localhost but it is limited(restricted) with student past records (from the MAIN sever) searching,etc ( course they can't access the centralized server ).They can add new students,payments and branch wise student recodes.So i'm going to sync the localhost with OUR online server when the NETWORK is ok.(we are going to have VPS).SO already we don't have branched networked system.So we need to have a VPN or something.So i'm asking what would be the ideal way ?

*My oneof server ADMIN says*

"a few month ago the company i worked for needed to set up a VPN system between offices in latvia and estonia. We bought [**I'll comment the URL**] thing (mostly because it's locally made - thus cheaper). It has capability of setting up a persistent VPN with loads of authentication options. Your university's network should already have much better equipment then this in place. It is only a matter of finding someone with clue, who can configure it."

Comment: http://routerboard.com/RB2011LS-IN

Answer (score 0):

Use Rsync, see [this](http://kb.liquidweb.com/using-rsync-to-transfer-and-synchronize-local-and-remote-systems/) and [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090817/copying-files-using-rsync-from-remote-server-to-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a VPN that allows secure communications between your branches and your VPS. If I understand correctly, all the branches will need to reach the VPS. In that case, you'd better install the VPN server on the VPS. Then all your branches will need VPN clients to establish tunnels to your VPN server.

The RouterBoard equipment you mentioned is a very affordable solution that does switching, routing, VPN services, among other things. I would personally suggest [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) which you can deploy using Linux machines or appliances. You may also use OpenVPN on RouterBoard OS.

What a Site-to-Site VPN does is connecting your networks together, as if they were local, allowing data traffic to be exchanged in a secure way over Internet connections.